# Can't see the difference between "While using the app" and "Only this time" options to grant permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

So I select "Only this time" option and permission is granted.

[image]

Then I close the app and open it again and then permission is granted right away, why?

So this dialog appear only once on app install and first start:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(
        arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    )
}
```

after you select "Only this time" it won't appear anymore.

p.s. tested on Samsung S22 Ultra.

**Update**: seems works fine for Pixel emulators, permission is always not granted on each app start

Comment: My experience with this selection is that "this time" actually has an (unspecified?) grace period after closing the app before permission ends up being revoked.